# NetBeans 7.0.1 Clean and Build Manifest Error

Tags: netbeans, build, manifest

I am doing a project for my class and I need to create a .jar file so it can be distributed. Although, when I click clean and build, it gives me an error:

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build
Updating property file: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/classes
Created dir: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/empty
Compiling 14 source files to /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/classes
Note: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/src/zzTeacherGUIPackage/TeacherLockGUI.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/src/zzTeacherGUIPackage/MarksAppGUI.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 1 file to /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/dist
Copying 1 file to /Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build
/Users/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/nbproject/build-impl.xml:676: Existing manifest /Use  rs/User/Desktop/School/Grade 11 (14 - 15)/Semester 1/01_ICS3UV/Unit 4/Programs/DevonDeruchie-ICS3UV/DevonDeruchie-G9Integer/build/null1454207832 is invalid
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)
```

I have no clue what this means or how to fix it... please help me. Also, I may add that I created a clock in netbeans and the clean and build process went perfectly, but this always gives an error. Also, could it be because I switched from a pc laptop to a MacBook Pro?

Comment: That's telling you it doesn't like something at line 676 in your build-impl.xml file so start there and make sure the xml is valid.  With xml files the line number in the error can be somewhat misleading as it may simply signal that elsewhere you didn't properly use a closing tag, etc.

Comment: I looked at the build-impl.xml file and on line 676 it opens a manifest tag. I remember the error saying something about an invalid manifest, what do you think? Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

After I had looked into the build-impl.xml file on line 676, i read further into the error code and it mention the nullxxx file (THATS THE MANIFEST :) ). I edited the manifest to add a splash screen but forgot about it. The code I had added  was in the wrong place. It was at the bottom when it shouuld have been in thhe middle! Hope this one helps others with the same prolem.